# Sublime Text3 the same snippets repeats

Tags: c++, autocomplete, sublimetext, code-snippets, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using sublime with some C++ package.
but I found when I was trying to use auto completes,

it came two options with whole the same snippets!

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I'm pretty sure the snippets is define by the "C++ Starting Kit" package

I've reinstall it but nothing change.

any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that one of them is the one that comes by default with sublime, and the other comes with the package you are using. If they have the same content, you can remove preferably the one that comes with the package, look for the proper files with *sublime-snippet* extension inside the package.